# how to delete a series of events from recurring set using ics file?

Tags: outlook, calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar, recurring-events

Im trying to delete a series of dates like google or zoom does ("delete this and following occurrences") but cant seem to delete them all

here is the code I'm using to do so
`RECURRENCE-ID;RANGE=THISANDFUTURE;TZID=America/New_York:20230221T100000Z`

I saw few people recommending to use UNTIL in the range parameter for recurrence-id but cannot find any syntax or working example.

Thanks in advance

Full code for creating recurring event:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID://Events//iCal 2.1//EN
METHOD:REQUEST
X-WR-CALNAME:Event Calendar
X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/New_York
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/New_York
TZURL:http://tzurl.org/zoneinfo-outlook/America/New_York
X-LIC-LOCATION:America/New_York
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0400
TZNAME:EDT
DTSTART:19700308T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
TZNAME:EST
DTSTART:19701101T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
TRANSP:OPAQUE
CREATED:20221221T094254Z
UID:TESTSC20221221094254
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20221226T110000
SUMMARY:deadline approaching Event
LOCATION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:Virtual Meeting
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20221226T100000
DTSTAMP:20221221T094254Z
ORGANIZER;CN=Events:mailto:events@abc.org
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=abc@abc.org;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:abc@abc.org
STATUS:CONFIRMED
DESCRIPTION:A. Want to join the meeting from your computer, tablet or smartphone?\n go to https://zoom.us/
SEQUENCE:0
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;UNTIL=20230228T110000Z
BEGIN:VALARM
DESCRIPTION:REMINDER
TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT10M
ACTION:DISPLAY
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Full code I use for deleting:

````
VERSION:2.0
PRODID://Events//iCal 2.1//EN
METHOD:CANCEL
X-WR-CALNAME:Event Calendar
X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/New_York
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
TRANSP:OPAQUE
CREATED:20221221T145554Z
UID:TESTSC20221221094254
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20221226T100000
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20221226T110000
SUMMARY:Event: deadline approaching Cancelled
LOCATION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:Virtual Meeting
DTSTAMP:20221221T145554Z
ORGANIZER;CN=Events:mailto:events@abc.org
RECURRENCE-ID;RANGE=THISANDFUTURE;TZID=America/New_York:20230221T100000Z
SEQUENCE:0
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=abc@abc.org;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:abc@abc.org
STATUS:CANCELLED
DESCRIPTION:This meeting has been deleted. Please contact HQ for scheduling a new meeting or more information about this.
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR```
````

Comment: Do you have a sample UID ? I want to make sure, you want to eliminate the whole recurrent event or just for example the next 2 weeks of that particular recurring event for example?

Comment: For UID: u can use the one in the example.
I want to delete the last 2 weeks of the one I schedule (according to ur example)
not the whole event

Comment: If these are events from Google Calendar, the way the UID is created, it has the original ID of the event and adding _ with info of the date, if possible you would need to loop based on the dates you might want to remove.

Comment: @RicardoJoseVelasquezCruz : Not using Google Calendar or any other calendar apps, using my own system to schedule meetings (recurring or otherwise) for various groups and committees. My code also generates the same ID for the events (see the examples above). Your suggestion doesn't work, tried that and something similar.